# Warn about references to int -0 used in array indexing

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
cout << a[-0] << std::endl;
```

This code will compile and print out `1`. All which is fine. I am assuming the compiler change the `-0` to a `0`.

Fun question: does the number system used in computers even allow `-0` as an `int` anymore?

I cant think of any reason that you would need `int -0` and it makes the code more confusing?

**Are there any flags (eg pedantic) that will throw a warning about this?**

*Background:* I found a bunch of these in some work code, have no idea why, but I want to make sure we know about them in the future.

Comment: Negative zero is a distinct number from positive zero for floating point numbers.

Comment: @univerio sure, but this is an `int` used to reference an array index?

Comment: Why *not?* It isn't wrong.

Comment: Compilers will also allow --1, ---1, etc. It's equally if not more difficult to prevent than it is to allow, in both cases. You're asking for a warning or error about something that isn't an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ permits 3 different representations for signed integers: 2's complement, 1's complement, and signed magnitude.

`-0` is not an integer literal, it's an *expression* consisting of a literal `0` with a unary `-` operator applied to it.

In 2's complement (which almost all modern systems use), there is only one representation for `0`, so `-0` has exactly the same value and representation as `0`.

In 1's complement and signed magnitude, there is a distinct representation for negative zero. (An integer is negated by inverting all the bits in 1's complement, by inverting the sign bit in sign magnitude, or by inverting all the bits and adding 1 in 2's complement. In the latter case, applying this operation to an all-bits-zero representation yields the same representation.)

I *think* that applying the unary `-` operator to the value `0` is required, or at least expected, to yield the same representation as `0` even if there's a distinct representation for negative zero, but I haven't been able to confirm this in a quick scan of the C++ standard. On a non-two's-complement system, it would be possible to create an `int` object that hold a negative zero representation; such an object's value should still compare equal to `0`.

In practice, this should not be a cause for concern; on a 2's-complement system `-0 == 0`.

If a compiler produced a warning for `-0`, it would be because the `-` is useless, not because it's incorrect.

(It would be interesting to know *why* those occurrences of `-0` exist in your code.)

Comment: Thanks, this is good. I would like to know about the occurrences of the `-0` as well. Maybe a joke that made it into the repository????

Answer (score 6):

You're looking at it backwards. It is in fact pointless writing code in the compiler to *not* let this program compile since, as you say, the expression `-0` is entirely valid and equivalent to `0`.

You'd have to introduce a new special case for unary `-` applied to integer literals with this particular value... and for what?

If you're writing confusing code then frankly that's your own fault; the compiler didn't make you do it.

Comment: I agree, and I wish the person who wrote the code still worked here so i could ask him to fix it. But there exists ways to warn the user about poorly written code, for example unused lines `1 + 3;` can throw warnings with flags, is there a way to do it here?

Comment: @Ben I'm not aware of any mainstream toolchain that may be configured to warn on this usage, no. Statements with discarded effects are *far* more general than this tiny corner case you've uncovered!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I realized that the preamble and the question I wanted answered didn't really make sense with each other so i have edited it.

Answer (score 1):

One of the earlier passes of the compile probably will do some simplifying of constant terms: for example, it will probably turn `int x = 0x100 | 0x001` into `int x = 5`.  The negative zero probably gets simplified during this pass.

Warning on `-0` in certain contexts would increase compiler complexity for very little gain.